# Register celery periodic tasks to see it within django admin

Tags: python, django, redis, celery, djcelery

I am trying to code some **periodic background tasks** *within Django and Celery*.

My tasks are **working** well, I manage to start those periodically when launching my celery worker with beat scheduler :
`celery -A parifex worker -B -l info`
[Discovered tasks by the worker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZjF9.png)

As you can see in the above image, my tasks are **well discovered**. However, *the autodiscover on INSTALLED_APPS was not working* as expected, so I had to **include** the path to the app where I want to find tasks in **Celery instantiation**.

### Requirements

```
pip freeze |grep "celery\|Django"
celery==4.4.1
Django==3.1.2
django-celery==3.3.1
```

---

### Into the base app where settings stands:

#### celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

import os

from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'parifex.settings')

# Define the Celery configuration and include <app>.tasks to discover it
app = Celery('parifex', include=['device.tasks'])

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS, force=True)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

#### settings.py

```
djcelery.setup_loader()
CELERYD_HIJACK_ROOT_LOGGER = False

# http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-redirect-stdouts-level
CELERY_REDIRECT_STDOUTS = True  # par défaut
CELERY_REDIRECT_STDOUTS_LEVEL = 'DEBUG'

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://:Redi$DB_withCelery@127.0.0.1:6234'
# store schedule in the DB:
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://:Redi$DB_withCelery@127.0.0.1:6234'

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']  # Ignore other content
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Paris'
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True

CELERY_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERYD_POOL_RESTARTS = True
```

---

### Into a module app called Device

#### tasks.py

```
from celery import shared_task
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from djcelery.schedulers import DatabaseScheduler, ModelEntry

from .models import Device
from .api.tools import TestDeviceApi


@shared_task
def count_devices():
    return Device.objects.count()


@shared_task(serializer='json', bind=True)
def get_devices_state():
    device_status = {}
    print(serialize('json', Device.objects.all()))
    for device in Device.objects.all():
        status = TestDeviceApi(device).ping()
        device_status[device.id] = (serialize('json', [device]), status)
    return device_status


@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*/1')))
def print_random():
    print(15)
```

---

Well, as I said, my worker discovers tasks fine, but my admin page within Django does not see it.

**First question :** How to register my tasks in order to see it in admin page, when creating periodic tasks by its page ? Or it is useless ?
[Registered Tasks my admin page can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsE4f.png)

**Second question :** Is it possible to see hardcoded *periodic tasks* within admin page without any other module to install ? Is there a 'built-in' way to do this ? Or perhaps, may I have to try saving it on my own, each time the task is called ?

My goal is to let the user capability to change scheduling on his own on tasks with a default behavior.

Thanks in advance for your help ! I hope I am clear.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem.

I fixed it by adding these lines to proj/proj/__init__.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals

from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

Unsure if this is the best solution or just a  work around but apparently this will make sure the app is imported when Django starts for shared_task to use.